# toast message android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, toast

I am trying to pop up a toast message as long as the phone rings and destroy the toast them the call is rejected or answered.

In the `OnReceive` method  I have something like this:

```
Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
final String state=bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
{
  Toast toast= new Toast(context);
  toast.show();

  new CountDownTimer(3500,1000)
{

@Override
public void onFinish()
{
  if (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)||
     (state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
  {
    toast.cancel();
  }
  else
  {
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    start();
  }
}
```

The problem is that even after the call is hanged up the toast message keeps poping up. It's like the state is never in the HANG_UP  or IDLE Mode.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: use something else popupwindow,dialog..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your broad cast recievere on recieve use this

```
 @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
               Log.d("INCOMING", "service start");
               TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
               try {
                 Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
                 Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                 m.setAccessible(true);
               //  telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
                 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                 String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("incoming_number");

                 Log.d("INCOMING", phoneNumber);

                 if ((phoneNumber != null) && !phoneNumber.equals(selectedtednumber)) { 
                     Toast.makeText(context, "Someone other calling sending to voice mail ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     sendToVoiceMail();
                 }
}
```

Comment: i don't understant . what is class c? what is this code doing?

Comment: c is an object of class for more see this http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: can't you just do Class c = tm.getClass(); ?

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong usage of the Toast feature. You should find a another way to do whatever you trying to do.

I think the closest thing that matches your need is [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). Check out the documentation.

Comment: A toast is to be displayed for a predefined duration i.e. LENGTH_LONG or SHORT.. You need to define the duration before hand.

Comment: I guess the RINGING broadcast is sent multiple times and your Toasts are queued up. One of them gets cancelled and the rest continue showing for full duration...

Comment: i see. thz for response. how to change my code with popup windows or is it possible to cangel all the toats from the queue?

Comment: Check if the Toast is already showing before showing in receiver.. Make the toast a member of your class.. and set a very long duration..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10224/discussion-between-user1222905-and-userseven7s)